Encountering java.lang.ClassCastException with Hilt Dependency Injection in Android while applying proguard rules
I have created an Android library. When I use it as an AAR file without enabling ProGuard, it works fine. However, when I enable ProGuard rules, it stops working.
I am using it as below in my app module
debugImplementation files('libs/stilib-debug.aar')

How can I resolve this issue?
Error Logs
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.app.sti.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$FragmentCImpl cannot be cast to com.example.app.stilib.ui.dialog.kyc.BenefitsDialog_GeneratedInjector
                                                                                                        at com.example.app.stilib.ui.dialog.kyc.Hilt_BenefitsDialog.inject(Hilt_BenefitsDialog.java:102)
                                                                                                        at com.example.app.stilib.ui.dialog.kyc.Hilt_BenefitsDialog.onAttach(Hilt_BenefitsDialog.java:52)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1881)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onAttach(DialogFragment.java:466)
                                                                                                        at com.example.app.stilib.ui.dialog.kyc.Hilt_BenefitsDialog.onAttach(Hilt_BenefitsDialog.java:39)
                                                                                                        at com.example.app.stilib.ui.dialog.kyc.Hilt_BenefitsDialog.onAttach(Hilt_BenefitsDialog.kt:90)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:3063)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:464)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:254)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

My Dialog Code
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BenefitsDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

companion object {
        fun newInstance(isShowFrom: String): BenefitsDialog {
            val dialog = BenefitsDialog()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString(BenefitsDialog.IS_SHOWN_FROM.name, isShowFrom)
            dialog.arguments = bundle
            return dialog
        }
    }

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DialogBenefitsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding?.root
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dialog?.apply {
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            setCancelable(false)
        }
    }

}

Here is my Hilt Configuration
Project Gradle:
plugins {
    alias(core.plugins.android.app) apply false
    alias(core.plugins.android.library) apply false
    alias(core.plugins.kotlin) apply false
    alias("com.google.dagger.hilt.android:2.44") apply false
}

App Gradle :
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'
}

MyLib Gradle:
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
        kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'
    }

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

I have already added proguard rules in MyLib and App
# Keep Dependency Injection Framework related classes and methods
    -keep class dagger.hilt.** { *; }
    -keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
    -keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }

# Keep Hilt generated classes
-keep class com.example.app.stilib.Hilt_* {*;}
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking @dagger.hilt.EntryPoint class *
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking @dagger.hilt.android.EarlyEntryPoint class *
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * {
   @dagger.internal.InjectedFieldSignature <fields>;
}

# Keep classes generated by Hilt
    -keep class com.example.app.stilib.*Hilt* {
        *;
    }

## Dagger
-keep class dagger.** { *; }
-dontwarn dagger.internal.codegen.**


-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking @dagger.hilt.EntryPoint class *
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking @dagger.hilt.android.EarlyEntryPoint class *


I encounter same issue. Can you solve this issue ?
